# Kendo Grid Angular Assign selectedRows data value to variable

Tags: html, angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I am attempting to pull a single select from a Kendo grid to a variable so I can pass the id of the object to a route of the selected item.  I can see the variable of the object under selectedRows > dataItem but I can't seem to call any of the objects below it.

Plunker  https://plnkr.co/edit/1yLrC3EXkHREkgnMijgt?p=preview

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { products } from './products';
import { SelectableSettings } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `


    <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [selectable]="{ mode: 'single'}" [height]="500" (selectionChange)="selected($event)">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name" [width]="300"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsInStock" title="Units In Stock"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitsOnOrder" title="Units On Order"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ReorderLevel" title="Reorder Level"></kendo-grid-column>
    </kendo-grid>


`
})
export class AppComponent {
public gridData: any[] = products;
public selectedId: number;

constructor() { }

public selected(e){
  //Problem here 
  this.selectedId = e.selectedRows.dataItem(n => n.ProductId);

  console.log(selectedId);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the `ProductID` on the selected item, you'll need to use

```
this.selectedId = e.selectedRows[0].dataItem.ProductID;
```

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/Kd9jxi5WMuXLIYIxhXQx?p=preview

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you... Easy miss on my end.

Comment: No problem -- happy to help :)